# Drupal 7 settings.php and the end point URL for Alfresco Module

Tags: drupal-7, alfresco, cmis

Alfresco and Drupal with Alfresco module on same server works fine.

```
 - Alfresco 4.2e CE installed with defaults. (:8080)
 - Drupal installed on localhost (:80) 
 - CMIS with Alfresco 7.x-1.x-dev module.
 - - settings.php url = http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/cmis
 - - Alfresco module end point URL = http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api
```

**BUT**
Configuration of the Alfresco 7.x-1.x-dev module on a Drupal instance residing on a different server accessing the same repository using the Alfresco 7.x-1.x-dev doesn't work with the following settings.

Is this the correct configuration for the connector in settings.php where 198.xxx.xxx.xxx is the Alfresco public IP?

```
$conf['cmis_repositories'] = array(
  'default' => array(
    'user' => 'admin',
    'password' => 'admin',
    'url' => 'http://198.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/alfresco/service/api/cmis' // CMIS API on Alfresco server
      )
    );
```

What is the appropriate end point URL:
    http://198.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/alfresco/api doesn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you connect to the Alfresco server on port 8080? i.e. are you sure there's no firewalling or routing getting in the way?

Comment: Yes. I can get to the server on port :8080

Comment: This was a much longer reply... :-)  I can hit the repo and get folder info, open or down load files using spacestore ID's, webdav, sharepoint protocol, the "Repository Search" addon and more.

Answer (score 1):

The correct service URL for the AtomPub binding in Alfresco 4.2.e is:
/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.0/atom

Comment: Thanks Jeff,
Is that for the binding in the .php file or the end point URL for Module config?  

Perhaps the Alfresco Module doesn't need both the .php connector and it's only required for the CMIS Drupal module.

Still getting 401 Unauthourized.

Answer (score 0):

Jeff,

Thanks you ,
The correct service URL for the AtomPub binding in Alfresco 4.2.e is: /alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.0/atom is the correct end-point URL for the settings.php file for connecting Drupal to Alfresco using the CMIS-API and CMIS Views.

The CMIS Repository, CMIS Query and CMIS Views work great.

There is something wrong with some of the other components and the Alfresco module.  But these are Drupal things
Thanks